# Push'у, а Git мне пишет everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github

Я только начал пользоваться Git'ом. Я создал репозиторий на сайте. Склонировал его (скопировал ссылку на сайте, потом git clone), потом добавил (add'ом) нужный мне файл и скоммитил. Потом, я push'у, а он мне пишет everything up-to-date

Comment: А нужный файл такой же самый как после clone - похоже да? Тогда нечего апдейтить. А если... то вы потеряли инфу после clone.

Comment: Ну,  я сделал все, а потом заклонил. И что теперь делать?

Comment: Мб ты пытаешься запушить не ту ветку?

Comment: Вроде, работает. А что значит "fatal: pathspec 'attempt1_1' did not match any files"?

Comment: `attempt1_1` - не является файлом.

Comment: Я понял: надо указывать расширение. А как делать так, чтобы Гит сохранял все мои файлы? А то он вместо attempt1_1, сохранил attempt1_2, потом attempt1_3. А мне надо, чтобы он сохранял все

Comment: `git add *` а все в текущем и подкаталогах: `git add .`

Comment: Пишет "fatal: pathspec 'attempt1_1.java' did not match any files" Расширение же указано?!

Comment: В `git add` указывается, либо полный путь, либо путь относительно текущего каталога.

Comment: А что такое текущий каталог?

Comment: Каталог, из которого ты выполняешь команду.

Comment: Размести в вопросе скриншот страницы своего проекта на github с выбранной веткой (branch): `master`.

Comment: StackOverflow говорит, что следующий вопрос я смогу задать через четыре дня. А в комментариях не хочет показывать скрин

Comment: @Anton Скинь свой ФБ

Comment: Отредактируй этот вопрос. Или кинь ссылку на свой проект в github.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master

git checkout "своя ветка"
```

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй написать `git push origin master`

Comment: Everything up-to-date

Comment: А вы после clone вообще совершали какие-либо действия?
Если да, то что выдаёт git status?

Comment: Да, работал, собственно, пытался как-то заливать. git status выдает C:\Users\Admin\IdeaProjects\try1\src\com\benjamin\try1>git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'github/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../../../../.idea/workspace.xml
        ../../../../out/
        "../../../../\320\222\320\264\320\276\321\205\320\275\320\276\320\262\320\273\321\217\321\216\321\211\320\270\320\265 \321\204\320\270\320\273\321\214\320\274\321\213.txt"

Comment: У тебя есть только вышеперечисленные файлы, которые git может добавить в индекс. Все остальные файлы УЖЕ закомичены. Т.е. в файлах `attempt*` нет новых не закомиченных изменений.